# MySQL: Select DATE vs UPDATE date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a date saved in 3 columns (cause it was like that, cannot change that).

**day**, **month** and **year**

There are dates that doesnt exist.

Example:

year - month - day

2005 - 02 - 31

`SELECT DATE(CONCAT(2005, '-', 2, '-', 31));` returns NULL

but

`UPDATE table SET day = 28 WHERE DATE(CONCAT(2005, '-', 2, '-', 31)) IS NULL` returns error

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2005-2-31'

Question 1:

How is this possible?

Question 2:
I need to fix those dates. But I cannot find them by using DATE() function. Is there a different way?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: And the month should contain 2 digits: `02`

Comment: It works even with this format. And still doesnt explain why it works only with select. And I need to fix those dates in procedure.

Comment: @tttpapi Could we solve your problem?

Comment: @rb94 I wasnt able to solve it in MySQL and had to make a skript outside a DB. Even when I have SELECT that returns the wrong dates in update it just causes error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but I think it will work for you:

```
UPDATE table
SET day = CASE WHEN (month IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) AND day > 31) THEN 31
            WHEN (month IN (4, 6, 9, 11) AND day > 30) THEN 30
            WHEN ((year = 2000 OR mod(year, 4)) != 0 AND day > 28) THEN 28
            ELSE 29 END
WHERE ((month IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) AND day > 31)
    OR (month IN (4, 6, 9, 11) AND day > 30)
    OR (month = 2 
        AND (((year = 2000 OR mod(year, 4)) != 0 AND day > 28) 
            OR (mod(year, 4) = 0 AND day > 29))))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you cannot use `IS NULL` on a function like this:

This will also give you an error:

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(2005, '-', 2, '-', 31)) IS NULL;
```

> MySQL can perform the same optimization on col_name IS NULL that it can use for col_name = constant_value. For example, MySQL can use indexes and ranges to search for NULL with IS NULL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

This  happen because your update query is wrong

try using a proper update sintax like

```
UPDATE Your_table
set column = 1
WHERE DATE(CONCAT(2005, '-', 2, '-', 31)) IS NULL
```

this should update all the rows in your_table

After the problem related to th update sintax  in mysql doc you can find that

> Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the
>   “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00
>   00:00:00').

so the result of the firts select should be  '0000-00-00)

eventually try convert  the string in proper  date ..

```
  str_to_date(CONCAT(2005, '-', 2, '-', 31), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I fixed the UPDATE query. It was just example, not complete query. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @tttpapi  . i have added  a brief  comment in my answer .. hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

For Update, try this

```
UPDATE table SET yourField=1 WHERE (SELECT DATE(CONCAT(2005, '-', 2, '-', 31))) IS NULL;
```

Using sub query in `WHERE` condition may solve your problem

Comment: I've just tried that and it returns error:
`Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: Then add necessary  conditions in the sub query to return 1 row

Answer (score 0):

You might try an `UPDATE` something like this:

```
UPDATE theTable 
SET `day` = DAY(LASTDAY(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-01'))
WHERE MONTH(DATE(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-01')) + INTERVAL (`day`-1) DAY) 
      <> MONTH(DATE(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-', `day`)))
```

actually, from the docs on `LASTDAY()`, this(below) should work:

```
WHERE LASTDAY(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-', `day`)) IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

UPDATE table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2005, '-', 2, '-', 31),'%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL

Answer (score -2):

Probably because February doesnt have 31 days

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT('2005', '-', '01', '-', '31')),
       DATE(CONCAT('2005', '-', '02', '-', '31')),
       DATE(CONCAT('2005', '-', '03', '-', '31'))
FROM DUAL;
```

[image]

Comment: You get NULL because february doesnt have 31 day, can you see the output picture?

Comment: Have you even read the whole question? I know it returns NULL. But update DOESNT!

Comment: If you know why return `NULL` then why you ask `why is this possible?` I wont have to read the whole  text when the question is right there.

Comment: "Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2005-2-31' - how is this possible?" - it looks like this *exactly* explains your error to me...